# onClick function does not remove item in an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a button which when you click should remove a box from the list but it doesn't work. Can anyone see why?

```
const Box = (props) => {
    return (
        <>
            <div id={props.id} style={{height:`${props.height}em`, width:`${props.width}em`, backgroundColor: props.color }}>
             </div>
           <Button onClick={props.removeItem}/>
        </>

    );
};
export default Box;
```

```
const BoxList = () => {

const [boxes, setBoxes] = useState([{height: "", width:"", color:"", id:""}]);

const removeBox = (boxId) => {
   const updatedBoxList = boxes.filter(box => box.id !== boxId);
    setBoxes(updatedBoxList);  // this is where the update should happen
};

const boxesArray = boxes.map((box) => {
    return(
    <Box width={box.height}
         height={box.width}
         color={box.color}
         id={box.id}
         removeItem={removeBox}
    />
    )
});
[...]
```

Comment: your `removeBox` function takes an argument, `boxId`, but `<Button onClick={props.removeItem}/>` doesn't call it with a box id

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
const Box = (props) => {
    const removeItem = () => {
        props.removeItem(props.id);
    };
    return (
        <>
            <div id={props.id} style={{height:`${props.height}em`, width:`${props.width}em`, backgroundColor: props.color }}>
             </div>
           <Button onClick={removeItem}/>
        </>

    );
};
export default Box;
```

I've redefined your Box component so that it calls the `props.removeItem` function with the argument the function is expecting

Comment: Thank you, so i have to define the function in the same file and the and then pass the props with the argument the function is expecting up from inside there. OK understood.

Comment: There is an alternative -- inside your boxes.map function, you could do something like this instead: `removeItem={() => {removeBox(box.id)}}`, and keep your Box component as it was

Comment: oh ok so i can just pass the function in directly with the argument, that is good to know. I will remember this for next time!

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the boxId into removeItem. Right now it is being called with the click event as its argument.